# Do native Japanese speakers confuse "オーストリア" and "オーストラリア"

Tags: loanwords

Native English speakers sometimes mix up Austria and Australia ([example](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3474132/Whoops-CNN-mercilessly-mocked-online-mixes-Austria-Australia.html)).

Do native Japanese speakers sometimes mix up "オーストリア" and "オーストラリア"?

Comment: I've heard a native Japanese speaker mix up スウェーデン and スイス while acting as an interpreter... But then again, they're both Europe, so it might be a geography problem rather than a pronunciation one.

Comment: Australia building fence at Slovenian border (T▽T)

Comment: @Stenomatisk that mistake is also mentioned for English-speakers in https://www.reddit.com/r/europe/comments/3goamj/what_other_country_do_foreigners_mistake_your/

Comment: Once Austria embassy in Japan tried to change their spelling in Japanese into "オーストリー",  because many Japanese do mistake.. https://ja.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/オーストリア

Comment: @HayatoY let me try linking: [オーストリア#オーストリー表記](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%AA%E3%82%A2#.E3.82.AA.E3.83.BC.E3.82.B9.E3.83.88.E3.83.A9.E3.83.AA.E3.82.A2.E3.81.A8.E3.81.AE.E6.B7.B7.E5.90.8C)

Comment: @HayatoY I've seen plenty of etymology sections in a Wikipedia article, but I don't recall one having sub-sections, let alone four of them!

Comment: I guess that Austria is Kangaroo's land and Australia is kiwi's land. :^(

Comment: @Stenomatisk I guess it's Chinese that Sweden(瑞典) and Switzerland(瑞士) are confusing. I don't think スウェーデン and スイス are that much unless written in kanji.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, many people do. The katakana transcriptions of them are based on English, and so they sound.

There are other confusing country names in Japanese such as アルバニア{Albania} and アルメニア{Armenia}, アイルランド{Ireland} and アイスランド{Iceland}, or ウルグアイ{Uruguay} and パラグアイ{Paraguay}, but this one is especially infamous because both countries are well-known ones and likely to be on everybody's lips including those who're not particularly into geography.

If you write them in kanji, European Austria is 墺【おう】 and Oceanian Australia is 豪【ごう】 (濠) so there's no confusion. But the problem is Austrian 墺 is relatively less known and if you explain that it means "Austria", the chaos starts over again.

---

Further reading: [Runaway 'kangaroo' spotted in Austrian garden](http://www.thelocal.at/20150128/runaway-kangaroo-spotted-in-austrian-garden)

Comment: I confuse Iberia with Liberia.
In the case of Albania, there are two name of country, Balkan state and ancient Caucasian Albania, 
so that is more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

Any Japanese who knows Austria and Australia are different countries wouldn't confuse them. We pronounce Austria as オーストリア, オーストリヤ, or オーストリー (elder genaration tends to call this way. Conversly younger generation calls Italy as イタリー、while elder genaration tends to call it イタリヤ), and Australia as オーストラリア with a clear vocal distinction.

Answer (score 0):

It can happen in Japanese just like it can happen in English.